# Use the API of Google offline speech recognition: python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-api-python-client

I want to use the google api of speech recognition offline, this is my code but it works only online.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
     print ('Say Something!')
     audio = r.listen(source)
     print ('Done!')

text = r.recognize_google(audio)
print(text)
```

Comment: Google speech recognition API utilizes REST or gRPC calls, meaning that it requires an internet connection to communicate to whatever services you are using.